# Is data jpa from spring boot include orphanRemoval option?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot with data-jpa as a dependency and trying to add orphanRemoval to a parent
entity.

```
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id", nullable = false)        
    public MyEntity getMyEntity() {
        return myEntity;
    }
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

What I'm getting is compile error:

```
The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type ManyToOne
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orphanRemoval is

- not available to `ManyToOne`
- available to `OneToOne`

Comment: so I need to delete them myself yes?

Comment: As long as you confirm that it is an orphan you can remove it in order to have the functionality orphanRemoval=true.